# Domain .htaccess redirect issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to create some redirects with .htaccess but I never manage to get it fully functional. Maybe someone here can help me.

What I need is:

1. `http://domain.se` and `http://domain.com` to redirect to `http://www.domain.com`.
2. I also need `http://domain.se/somefolder`, `http://domain.com/somefolder` as well as `http://www.domain.se/somefolder` to redirect to `http://www.domain.com/folder`.

I've tried to accomplish this myself but all I end up with is errors about data not being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# folder rewrite
RewriteRule ^somefolder$ folder [L]

# domain redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =domain.se
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

1. This is to be placed in **.htaccess** file in website root folder. If placed elsewhere some tweaking may be required.
2. First rule will rewrite (internal redirect) requests to `/somefolder` to `/folder`. If you need this to be 301 Permanent Redirect, then replace `[L]` by `[R=301,L]`
3. Second rule will do domain redirect job. This rule will ONLY redirect if domain is `domain.com` or `domain.se`. If you want to have redirect from ANY domain name (that your webserver is configured can serve) to `www.domain.com` then replace those 2 RewriteCond lines with this one: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.domain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

That should meet all of your requirements. All requests that are not `www.domain.com` will be redirected to that domain, with the request URI intact.

Comment: Is there a reason you say you used the other code that was posted 27 minutes later but is the same, aside from being overly verbose?